# What platform/technology would work best for a web app that has heavy client-side excel type operations?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, excel

So, I am working on an app that needs heavy "cell" calculations in a web-based app. The client needs to be able to change values, even the formulas... calculate totals etc, all on the client side in basically a "spreadsheet".

These requirements are pretty strict :(

I am wondering if there is any library or any way to utilize Excel through a web page? Would Silverlight provide any benefit? One thing I was thinking about is that we need some of the same functionality on the client and server (formula calculating), so Silverlight would be great for the re-usability of our C#. Any help is greatly appreciated!

### EDIT 1: ## It is not a public facing application.

Comment: It is not a public facing application. Unless there is an API for private use?

Comment: Excel itself is not embeddable in Silverlight, however the SL toolkit's DataGridView might be a good starting point. Silverlight would certainly be faster than JavaScript and easier to work with than Flash :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered using Excel itself?  Could be a particularly good option for a non-public-facing app.

You can embed .NET code into Excel, including a custom UI and web services calls, with a technology called VSTO.  It gives you full programmatic control over cells, formulas, etc.  Very cool!

Answer (score 1):

Excel Web Services?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/ha101054761033.aspx

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) will do it.

[Here](http://gadgetopia.com/post/6788) is an article by Deane Barker who had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726432/how-do-you-use-excel-server-side) on stackoverflow.

Even Microsoft uses SpreadsheetGear for Excel based calculators on it's MSN Money site as you can see [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/customers/microsoft.msn.money.aspx).

You can find live ASP.NET samples [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/) and download the free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC