# Running VBA functions in a server side Access database from a WCF service

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, wcf, ms-access, vba

I've been researching for days and I've gotten to the point where my WCF service creates an Access object via com/interop.  I've ran the `OpenCurrentDatabase` call for the Access object without an error but `Application.CurrentDB` is still nothing/null.  If the `CurrentDB` is nothing then I surely can't call `Application.Run "myFunction"`  I realize WCF services aren't meant to be user interactive, but it's a long story why I'm trying to go this route.  Basically I need to have a proof of concept ready sooner rather than later and the alternative (correct) route involves the complete re-writing of a large complex access VBA application.  It's not a permissions issue, I have the IIS user names added to the security tab.  What I really need is a way to set `Environment.UserInteractive` to true so my WCF service can create an instance of Access on my server machine, run the VBA functions, close out, return true.  I'm using VS 2010 for the WCF, IIS 7 for my server, Access 2010 for the VBA application. Please help!

Comment: Can you just make the database run the function on startup?  i.e., make a form that is the startup form that runs the process, or make an AutoExec macro that calls the appropriate code so that you don't have to do anything else from .NET.

Comment: Yeah I came across that in my research but I'm considering trying that as a last resort because the entire VBA program wasn't intended to run from start to finish all at once.  One function exports a worksheet for our underwriters to complete and send back to the analyst.  Once it's returned, the analyst would fire off the import function.  It's possible to go this route, but the proof of concept will end up being us sitting in a room watching it work for 10 minutes and the boss won't see anything happening.

Comment: I'm not sure the autoexec macro allows for arguments, I guess I could write the name of the function I want to run to a txt file or database, then have the autoexec macro check the file for which function to run.  What a circus!

Comment: I guess you should expect that trying to do Access automation from a WCF service :-)  You will probably end up doing like we did with our application -- rewrite VBA logic into VB.Net libraries.

Comment: Ok, so here's my goofy solution.  The WCF service will write the functionName and argument information to a database on the service machine.  A desktop application on the server machine will monitor the database for new entries.  Once it finds a new entry written by the WCF service, it will execute the access DB function and write back to the service database the result.  The WCF service will be monitoring the DB for the result and send it back once it's found.

Comment: Yep. That's actually another kind of solution I had thought of (it's not really goofy at all), but wasn't sure if you had all the prerequisites to do it :-)  Let me know how it works.  If you have further issues you may want to start a new question, and add an answer with how you solved this question and mark as answered to close this question.  You may also want some service on the machine monitoring that the queue is being responded to in a timely fashion in case some part of the process breaks down.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use Excel server-side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726432/how-do-you-use-excel-server-side)

Comment: **Do not use** Access through interop in a server application. See the question I linked as a duplicate, as well as [Considerations for server-side Automation of Offic](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Comment: You've probably already shown you proof of concept, but have you tried making you wcf a windows service with interact with desktop set?

Comment: @JohnSaunders yeah the server side interop question you linked to is very similar, same concept, but I wouldn't say duplicate necessarily since I'm trying to perform access operations.  The solution mentioned spreadsheet gear but provides no "access gear" that would allow access macros to be executed on the server side.  Thanks anyway

Comment: @mellamokb I ended up using my solution in my comment posted on Sept 23rd.  Worked great for the demo

Comment: @brettville: you should create an answer with your solution. I would upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to have the WCF service write the access macro name to a database and have a desktop application on the server machine monitor the database. The desktop application loads access, performs the actions, and writes back to the database upon completion. The WCF service monitors the database waiting for an "operation complete" status and returns the result.