# Excel Macros on Informatica

Tags: vba, excel, informatica

I am trying to load an Excel which has macros, now challenge is to run the macros before loading that data, and we are using Informatica for data loading.

Do we have any way to run the Macros on Excel using informatica and then load the data?

Comment: You should investigate the topic of running Excel macros programmatically - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11149357/programmatic-execution-excel-macro-on-remote-machine-from-a-website or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10232150/run-excel-macro-from-outside-excel-using-vbscript-from-command-line.

Answer (score 0):

I am little bit confused about your question ( not  clear about the scenario you are describing). What I can suggest is:

Step 1: It will be great if you can convert the macro into a vbscript (.vbs file). Alternatively, if you find that tough, write a small vb script that will call the macro.  Follow the link Marek Grzenkowicz provided in comment.

Step 2: Add one command task in your informatica mapping. Then add this vbscript file name with full path in "commands" field so that when the command task will run, it will call the vbscript file.