# Publishing Asp.net web application with Interop.Excel dll for generating excel files

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, iis, web-deployment

The excel files are generated using code when i run application from visual studio.But when i publish asp.net web application it does not show excel file.

Things i have done: 
1)added reference to:1) Interop.excel.dll2)Interop.Microsoft.Office.Core.dll and Interop.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

2)Changed the property of all dll to Copy local=true.So the dlls are added in bin folder.

3)I debugged the application by attaching w3wp process but the code executes fine with no exception or errors but the excel is not generated
**Here is code for generating excel:**

```
 public class ExcelUtlity
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// FUNCTION FOR EXPORT TO EXCEL
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataTable"></param>
        /// <param name="worksheetName"></param>
        /// <param name="saveAsLocation"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public bool WriteDataTableToExcel(System.Data.DataTable dataTable, string worksheetName, string saveAsLocation, string ReporType, string fromdate, string todate, string pubicationname)
        {
            Excel.Application excel;
            Excel.Workbook excelworkBook;
            Excel.Worksheet excelSheet;
            Excel.Range excelCellrange = null;

            try
            {
                // Start Excel and get Application object.
                excel = new Excel.Application();

                // for making Excel visible
                excel.Visible = true;
                excel.DisplayAlerts = false;

                // Creation a new Workbook
                excelworkBook = excel.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

                // Workk sheet
                excelSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelworkBook.Sheets[1];
                excelSheet.Name = worksheetName;


                excelSheet.Cells[1, 1] = ReporType;
                excelCellrange = excelSheet.get_Range("A1", "C1");
                excelCellrange.Merge(3);
                if (pubicationname != "")
                {
                    excelSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "PublicationName :- " + pubicationname;
                    excelCellrange = excelSheet.get_Range("A2", "C2");
                    excelCellrange.Merge(3);
                }
                else
                {

                }
                excelSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "From Date :- " + fromdate + " To Date :- " + todate;
                excelCellrange = excelSheet.get_Range("A3", "C4");
                excelCellrange.Merge(3);
                // excelSheet.Cells[1, 2] = "Date : " + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();

                // loop through each row and add values to our sheet
                int rowcount = 6;

                foreach (DataRow datarow in dataTable.Rows)
                {
                    rowcount += 1;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                    {
                        // on the first iteration we add the column headers
                        if (rowcount == 7)
                        {
                            excelSheet.Cells[6, i] = dataTable.Columns[i - 1].ColumnName;
                            excelSheet.Cells.Font.Color = System.Drawing.Color.Black;

                        }

                        excelSheet.Cells[rowcount, i] = datarow[i - 1].ToString();

                        //for alternate rows
                        if (rowcount > 7)
                        {
                            if (i == dataTable.Columns.Count)
                            {
                                if (rowcount % 2 == 0)
                                {
                                    excelCellrange = excelSheet.Range[excelSheet.Cells[rowcount, 1], excelSheet.Cells[rowcount, dataTable.Columns.Count]];
                                    //    FormattingExcelCells(excelCellrange, "#CCCCFF", System.Drawing.Color.Black, false);
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }

                // now we resize the columns
                excelCellrange = excelSheet.Range[excelSheet.Cells[1, 1], excelSheet.Cells[rowcount, dataTable.Columns.Count]];
                excelCellrange.EntireColumn.AutoFit();
                Excel.Borders border = excelCellrange.Borders;
                border.LineStyle = Excel.XlLineStyle.xlContinuous;
                border.Weight = 2d;


                excelCellrange = excelSheet.Range[excelSheet.Cells[1, 1], excelSheet.Cells[2, dataTable.Columns.Count]];
                //  FormattingExcelCells(excelCellrange, "#000099", System.Drawing.Color.White, true);


                //now save the workbook and exit Excel


        //        excelworkBook.SaveAs(saveAsLocation);
                //excelworkBook.Close();
                //excel.Quit();
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                excelSheet = null;
                excelCellrange = null;
                excelworkBook = null;
            }

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// FUNCTION FOR FORMATTING EXCEL CELLS
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="range"></param>
        /// <param name="HTMLcolorCode"></param>
        /// <param name="fontColor"></param>
        /// <param name="IsFontbool"></param>
        public void FormattingExcelCells(Excel.Range range, string HTMLcolorCode, System.Drawing.Color fontColor, bool IsFontbool)
        {
            range.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(HTMLcolorCode);
            range.Font.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(fontColor);
            if (IsFontbool == true)
            {
                range.Font.Bold = IsFontbool;
            }
        }

    }
```

Please guide me as to what changes i can do so that it can work on iis.

Comment: Can you show your code of the "saving excel file" method? Is the directory's permission write-permitted?

Comment: No i dont save file the user saves file if wanted,the file is autogenerated at this line:excel = new Excel.Application();excel.Visible = true; when i run from visual studio

Comment: Server side Office automation is not supported, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you use Excel server-side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726432/how-do-you-use-excel-server-side)

Comment: ASP.Net application with excel interop not a good idea.